# Why does this HTML crash IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, crash

I have a page that causes IE 8 to crash. I've dumbed it all the way down to just the html/javascript that causes the crash.
I know I'm going to have to do something different for displaying the page how I want in IE without breaking it. Is anyone aware of a way that I can report this to the IE team to get it fixed?

The crash happens when you mouse over the span. Create a scratch .html file to test. Using jsfiddle doesn't crash it.

Update: Make sure IE isn't in compatibility mode to get it to crash.
Update2: It crashes in safe mode too, so it isn't an add-on causing the problem. I have tried it on multiple computers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .condPartHover
        {
            border-color: #000000;
            background-color: #E5F0F9;
            color: #1D5987;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <ul>
    <li>
        <div>Testing:
            <div style="position:relative; display:inline-block; height:25px;">
                <span style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; border:1px solid #000000; background-color:White;" onmouseover="this.className = 'condPartHover';">test
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't crash for me. Try [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/kjyvv/)

Comment: My IE8 does not crash on this html.  The first 2 comments are irrelevant and unconstructive.

Comment: @xbrady, can you reproduce the crash in [safe mode](http://www.mitchellenright.com/2010/12/28/internet-explorer-safe-mode/)?

Comment: @Martin. On [jsfiddle it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/dCwCT/). Create a html file, fill it with the one in this post, and open it on IE8 and the browser will hang up. Strange IE :P

Comment: Make sure you don't have IE in compatibility mode. I've tested this on several computers here at work.

Comment: Not sure if it's good or bad that I have an urge to start Windows XP Mode just for this.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi It still crashes in safe mode.

Comment: @James Did you pull the page up from a .html file you created, or did you jsfiddle?

Comment: I pasted your code into a html file and opened it from my computer's filesystem (not from a web server).  Running IE8 on Win7/64

Comment: I can get it to crash on IE8. Looking into fix for it now... Also, as a note, looks like it crashes after the `this.className` line is run. Almost like it is trying to run more code.

Comment: Looks like I messed up the copy paste and didnt grab the doctype.  When I use your doctype it crashes.

Comment: I'll save this code for a possible future use! :)

Comment: IE9 reports that it blocked an ActiveX control from running.

Comment: @Rob that's because you run it as standalone `.html` file it will block any JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is anyone aware of a way that I can report this to the IE team to get
>   it fixed?

Yes, go to http://connect.microsoft.com/ , enter "Internet Explorer Feedback Program" in the search box and it'll give you a link to report bugs like this to the IE team. They do read/act on them, though don't expect anything quick. Whether a bug in an old version of IE is deemed worthy of fixing I don't know though. It might be only security fixes that are still applied to IE8 nowadays, not any fix that will change the HTML rendering or Javascript behaviour.

Comment: It looks like this only works for IE 9/10. Maybe there is no way to report bugs for older browsers? You would think they would still support IE 8 since they decided to not allow installing IE 9+ on Windows XP. If no one else can find a place to report IE 8 bugs then I'll just mark this as answer.

Comment: Fair enough, but Connect seems like the proper bug reporting mechanism for lots of Microsoft's products. If they won't accept it there, I'd guess they won't accept bug reports any other way too. I agree that you'd think they should still support IE8 while XP lives on at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try with mouseOver or mouseEnter with jQuery.

```
$('span').mouseover(function() {
  $('span').addClass("condPartHover");
});
```

In addition this method you are using is not HTML valid anymore.

Comment: To clarify, is the question "how do I fix this?" or "How do I report the bug to Microsoft"?  If you're just looking for a fix, why even use script at all?  Just use `:hover`

Comment: I was using the jquery hover function before. I just stripped it out to where it crashed IE. $('span').hover(
        function () { $(this).addClass('condPartHover'); },
        function () { $(this).removeClass('condPartHover'); } //Still crashes IE
    );

Comment: It is the className update that is triggering the crash. addClass updates the className property which causes it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your doctype is incorrect and you are in quirks mode. If you must use the xhtml doctype, use this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: There is a distinct difference between the `strict` and `transitional` doctypes that should not be overlooked.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Yes but his is not a valid xhtml transitional one either. New web pages have no need for transitional and one should always use strict.  http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: I disagree wholeheartedly. Many common attributes and values are acceptable in `transitional` while not being acceptable in `strict` (for example: `[target="_blank"]`). If you're going to recommend anything, you should be recommending the HTML 5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @zzzzBov - Transitional doctypes are for those pages transitioning away from using old, deprecated markup. New web pages should not be using such things. The reason I didn't recommend the new doctype is because he showed an interest in the xhtml one as I said in the OP.

Comment: True, I ended up with the posted doctype because I was trying several and they all caused IE to crash. I've updated the doctype. This still however causes IE to crash.